# Why is this an Outer Join per Access?

Tags: ms-access, outer-join

I have a table UPDATES, consisting of updates to location-specific product prices, with the four fields (update date, location, product, price).

The dimensions (update date, location, product) form via concatenation a field which is a primary key for UPDATES and passes referential integrity.

I want a new table MASTER showing the prices each calendar day for each product at each location, as the last updated price.

I also have the following 3 tables:

DATES (2 fields: calendar day (primary key), (date of last update))

LOCATIONS (location (primary key))

PRODUCTS (product (primary key))

(nb: I've used VBA to attach the date of last update to each calendar day.)

I have left-joins defined for each of these 3 tables with UPDATES, on each of update date, location and product.

When I attempt to form the table MASTER, (calendar day, location, product, price) I am receiving the "ambiguous outer join" error message. But there is, in fact, no actual ambiguity, as there is only one possible value for the price for each row in the table I am forming. Each calendar day in MASTER is associated with a unique date of last update, and this date of last update, along with the joined Location and Product fields, uniquely identifies the desired record in the table UPDATES.

Access acknowledges this as each of the outer joins was defined in the Relationships with Enforce Referential Integrity with no errors returned.

I realize this is a beginner's question and will be down-voted but I have spent two full days trying to find a simple example on the internet to follow.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT DATES.DATE, DATES.UPDATE, LOCATIONS.LOCATION, PRODUCTS.PRODUCT, UPDATES.PRICE
FROM (DATES LEFT JOIN (LOCATIONS LEFT JOIN (PRODUCTS LEFT JOIN UPDATES ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCT = UPDATES.PRODUCT) ON LOCATIONS.LOCATION = UPDATES.LOCATION) ON DATES.UPDATE = UPDATES.UPDATE);
```

Comment: Short answer: It's an outer join because you have used `LEFT JOIN` in your SQL statement. If you know for sure that there will always be a match on the joined columns between each table then you can use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: thank you very much. I'm an idiot.

Comment: I fully understand the flaw in my logic. While I had created a primary key from the 3 dimensions, Access need not "remember" this. I needed to create a unique multidimensional index melding the 3 dimensions instead. Thanks for tolerating stupid here.